# How to show that the deltoid is a plane algebraic curve of degree $4$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, plane-geometry

> How can I show that a deltoid is a plane algebraic curve of degree 4?

I have searched that the parametric equation for deltoid is given by
$$\begin{align}
x&= 2 \cos t + \cos 2t \\
y&=2 \sin t - \sin 2t
\end{align}$$

So, by using some trigonometric properties, we can write
$$\begin{align}
x = 2 \cos t + 2 \cos^2 t - 1  &\quad\to\quad x^2 = \phantom{-}4 \cos^4t + 8\cos^3 t - 4 \cos t + 1 \\
y =2 \sin t -2\sin t \cos t\;\, &\quad\to\quad y^2=-4 \cos^4t+ 8 \cos^3t -8\cos t+4 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) setting $c=\cos(t), s=\sin(t)$ using $c^2+s^2-1=0$:

```
R=QQ[c,s,x,y,MonomialOrder=>Lex]
I=ideal(c^2+s^2-1,x-(2*c+c^2-s^2),y-(2*s-2*s*c))
gens gb I
```

yields $x^4-8x^3+2x^2y^2+18x^2+24xy^2+y^4+18y^2-27$ or as [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_curve) puts it (for $b=3, a=1$): $$(x^2+y^2)^2+18(x^2+y^2)-27=8(x^3-3xy^2).$$

Comment: any hint if we try to prove that deltoid is algebraic manually? without using any program?

Comment: @France To find the equation I would still try to mimic what the software does: that is use Gröbner bases. If you only want to verify the equation, that is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Write the equations as

$
x=2c^2+2c-1\\
y^2=-4c^4+8c^3-8c+4
$

where $c=\cos t$.
Feeding

```
Eliminate[{x==2c+2c2-1,y2=-4c^4+8c^3-8c+4},c]
```

to [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eliminate%5B%7Bx%3D%3D2c%2B2c2-1,y2%3D-4c%5E4%2B8c%5E3-8c%2B4%7D,c%5D)
gives
$$
x^4 - 8 x^3 + x^2 (2 y^2 + 18) + 24 x y^2 = -y^4 - 18 y^2 + 27
$$
You can do this by hand by computing the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $2c^2+2c-1-x$ and $-4c^4+ 8 c^3 -8c+4-y^2$, seen as polynomials in $c$.

The resultant is the determinant of this $6 \times 6$ [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix):
$$
\pmatrix{
              2 & 2 & -x-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 2 & 2 & -x-1 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & -x-1 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & -x-1 \\
              -4 & 8 & 0 & -8 & 4-y^2 & 0 \\
              0 & -4 & 8 & 0 & -8 & 4-y^2 \\
}
$$
It will take some work to compute this determinant by hand but it's not impossible.

However, you don't need to compute the determinant to prove that the curve is algebraic, because the determinant is clearly a polynomial in $x$ and $y$. It is also clear that its is degree $4$.

Comment: can we show that it is algebraic without using a program such as wolframAlpha?

Comment: Thanks @lhf. But why is it a 15X15 matrix? the first polynomial is of degree 2 and the second is of degree 4.

Comment: pls help me understand. From what i read (and understood) in the link you provided, the matrix should be $(m+n) \times (m+n)$ matrix, where $m$ is the degree of the first polynomial, and $n$ is the degree of the second polynomial.

Comment: @France, you're right, I misread. Perhaps we can clear the comments now?

Comment: FWIW, you can do the Gröbner basis computation directly in *Mathematica*: `GroebnerBasis[Append[TrigExpand[Thread[{x, y} == {2 Cos[t] + Cos[2 t], 2 Sin[t] - Sin[2 t]}]], Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2 == 1], {x, y}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]`